# RxJs: Sequence of Web Request. What's a better solution than mine?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I have an array of N (integer) urls. I want to make web requests.

**Requirements**

1. update status: we are starting to make web requests
2. Requests are made one after another
3. Before each web request we update the status which URL we are going to call.
4. Update status: Finish (after all urls received)

I want to emit following events

- Begin with urls
- Emit: String: Staring web requests

Loop Start (urls should be loaded 1 after another, not all at once. Data is emitted as soon as its received)

- Emit: String: Loading url N[i]
- Emit: Object: Data of url N[i]

Loop End

- Emit: String: Finish

Following is my solution. I am looking for better solution

[https://jsbin.com/kotizid/edit?html,js,console](http://jsbin.com/dajuwoxigo/edit?js,console)

```
//Fake Webrequest. Returns a promise
function fakeWebrequest(url){
    return new Promise(function(resolve){
        console.log('Making Web request for: '+url);
        setTimeout(function(){
          resolve('RESPONSE: of: '+ url);
        },500);
    });
}


//Urls lists
//null added at end to indicate end. Its a hack
let urls$ = Rx.Observable.of(['url 1','url 2',null]);


//Status Update
let status1$= urls$.map(()=>'Start downloading...')

//Queue
let queue$ =  urls$.flatMap((url)=>url)
              .concatMap((url)=>{
                    if(url==null){
                        return Rx.Observable.of(null)
                    }
                    let status$= Rx.Observable.of(`Loading ${url}`);
                    let promise$= Rx.Observable.fromPromise(fakeWebrequest(url))
                    return status$.merge(promise$);
              })

let finalSeq$ = status1$.merge(queue$);



finalSeq$.subscribe(function(res){
    if(res==null){
        //End
    }else{
        console.log(res);
    }    
})
```

**Problems with my code**

1. null added at end of url
2. Subscribe event has to handle different type of data, which mean I have to add ifs to guess which event was fired. eg if res in subscribe is string it must be status. if its null sequence must have ended.

I am looking for a better solution. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understood your problem correctly, a possible solution would be :

```
const { Observable } = Rx;

// fake http request
function fakeWebrequest(url){
    return Observable
        .of(`RESPONSE: of: ${url}`)
        .delay(500);
}


const urls = ['url 1','url 2'];

let requests$ = Observable.from(urls.map(url => fakeWebrequest(url)));

requests$
  .concatAll()
  .subscribe(
    // next
    res => {
      console.log(res)
    },
    // error
    _ => {},
    // complete
    _ => console.log('All requests ended')
  );
```

The output is the following :

```
RESPONSE: of: url 1
RESPONSE: of: url 2
All requests ended
```

http://jsbin.com/muquzuwexa/edit?js,console

Comment: it has 2 problems. a> Making all web requests at once. b> How are we going to emit status before making web requests

Comment: It doesn't make all requests at once. Try to put a console.log within a do before the delay. It's just creating a cold observable, which is not triggered right away. What do you mean by status ? If you want to log something like "Request to fetch ${url} has been started" before each request, put it in a do  and console.log it before `.of(`RESPONSE: of: ${url}`)`

Comment: Put a console in your `fakeWebrequest ` and you will se that it gets immediately called. By `status` I mean emitting an event with string, just before making each web request. You can check my JSBIN link, and try to simulate the same behaviour. JSBIn is down rightnow so you may have to weight.

Comment: The function is immediately called : YES. But it just returns an observable. For real, I can imagine that instead of `Observable.of` you'll have `http.get('...')` or a post, put etc, right ? Well angular uses an observable and your request won't be fired until you subscribe to it. The point is, you "prepare" the requests and you do not fire them.

Comment: YES, function is called but observable "body" is not called immediately but in sequence way for each url - everythig is ok :) . Here my case: 
            `let requests  = this.meta.gallery2DImageFiles.map(
            photo => {
                return this.interiorService.uploadGallery2DImage(interiorId,  photo.file); // here angular http observable is created
            }
        );

        requests.push(new Observable( photo => { ... }));

        req.concatAll().subscribe(...)`